# Prevent to insert the blank row in table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have html table with 4 row when all row have data it insert all record to database as i want, but when only 1 or 2 row have data then also it inserting the 4 rows to database like 2 with data and 2 rows blank.i need to prevent the black row insertion to database..How to Solve..Thanks in advance..

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
            Dt.Columns.Add("StudentName");
            Dt.Columns.Add("RegistrationNumber");
            Dt.Columns.Add("Department");
            Dt.Columns.Add("FatherName");
       for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
            {

                string StudentName = Request.Form["name" + i].ToString();
                string RegistrationNumber = Request.Form["reg" + i].ToString();
                string Department = Request.Form["dep" + i].ToString();
                string FatherName = Request.Form["Fname" + i].ToString(); 
                Dt.Rows.Add(StudentName, RegistrationNumber, Department, FatherName);


            }
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DUM"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "InsertStudentDetails";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DetailInsersion", Dt);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                lblStatus.Text = "Details Saved into Database";
            }
            catch (Exception es)
            {
                throw es;
            }
            }
```

Comment: maybe an `ìf` before you `Dt.Rows.Add(...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you simply check if it's empty, for example:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    string StudentName = Request.Form["name" + i].ToString();
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(StudentName))
        continue;
    string RegistrationNumber = Request.Form["reg" + i].ToString();
    string Department = Request.Form["dep" + i].ToString();
    string FatherName = Request.Form["Fname" + i].ToString(); 
    Dt.Rows.Add(StudentName, RegistrationNumber, Department, FatherName);
}
```

Maybe you want to use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` or you want to check all strings. It's just an example.  But apart from that, you should do validation via [ASP.NET validators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx). If the field is mandatory you should use a [`RequiredFieldValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check your inputs before adding them as row.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

    // read from form into string variables ...

    var doWriteToDb = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StudentName)
                   || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RegistrationNumber)
                   || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Department)
                   || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FatherName);

    if (doWriteToDb) {
        Dt.Rows.Add(StudentName, RegistrationNumber, Department, FatherName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this code.i hope it help you.

```
public bool IsValid {
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(StudentName) &&
               !string.isNullOrEmpty(your other field)...;
        // I'm just guessing here what controls your form has. you should see the point though
    }
}
```